# Problems retrieving Data using stored procedure in asp.net web service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, visual-studio-2010, stored-procedures

i have this stored procedure in my DataBase:

```
Select something From somewhere Where Id = @Id  And Category in (Select carId From CarCategory where..)
```

when i test this stored procedure in the **Visual Studio** *Execute*  it works just fine

**But** When i call my web service function that uses this procedure it doesn't give me any results (the *DataSet* retrieved is empty)

so i had no choice but to rewrite the stored procedure in like this:

```
 Select somthing From somewhere Where Id = @Id  And Category = @Category
```

But that isn't what i really want i want the previous method to function.

**more info on this problem:**

I think that the *remote server*  can't access the *CarCategory* table to get the data,,, is that possible??

because when i use another stored procedure to call a function that call a another procedure to get info from *CarCategory* it doesn't work and send me an error.

Why cant the server find any row,, there is plenty of rows should be retrieved it is really annoying, i cant figure out why can any one help??????????????

***this error is:***

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: There is no row at position 0.
   at System.Data.RBTree`1.GetNodeByIndex(Int32 userIndex)
   at System.Data.DataRowCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at Selling_Agency.categoryNameToID(String Name) in e:\from moaaz\WEB SERVICES\carBroker_SellingAgency1\App_Code\Selling_Agency.cs:line 68
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Comment: Can you include the code your calling the stored procedure with?

Comment: PLEASE watch your formatting. Look at your post after you post it!

Answer (score 1):

Check your connection string make sure which user it has.

If it uses integrated security / windows authentication, then notice that the web service will be using ASP.NET account not your account. This could be the reason it cannot access the DB. If so, you can solve by using SQL authentication for example.